# Spring Maven mutimodule project with common test resources not picking up properties

Tags: spring, maven, unit-testing, spring-boot

I have a multimodule Spring Maven project with structure:

- Parent

  - Child_A

    - Child_B

In **Child_A** I create a common test-jar as follows:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

and I want to use it in **Child_B** and **Parent** so I added the dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now in **Child_B** I can access the classes which are in the test-jar, but for some reason, I can't access the properties file. I looked in the jar and the properties file was there.

I **Child_A** I have a common test class which has the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@Getter
```

and also I have **TestMainClass** there which is same as normal Spring main class what extends SpringBootServletInitializer.

I have read many post here and they all refer to creating the test-jar and all should work but still for some reason I cannot access the properties.

What am I missing?

Comment: If child_A is a parent and has a module Child_B I expect that your build failing cause a if a Child_A is a parent which contains modules it can't create a jar cause it has no code at all...

Comment: Hmm, Child_A is added as a dependecy to Child_B which is added to Parent. Child_A builds fine but Child_B can't access the properties which are generated in Child_A (it can access the classes).

Comment: You posts says something different about your project structure...furthermore add the classifier `tests` to your dependency see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html

Comment: Where do you checked the jar file? Inside the target folder or inside your m2 repo folder?

Comment: Already tried that and the default value for classifier is tests anyway.

Comment: I checked the jar in my target folder.